# error if i try to loop an event in terraform

Tags: terraform, aws-glue

I am trying to loop an event pattern in cloudwatch but i am getting errors. not sure if i am doing this in correct way.

```
resource "aws_cloudwatch_event_rule" "failed_event" {
name        = "failed-event"
description = "failed event"


for value in range(length(var.values)):
{
event_pattern = <<PATTERN
{
"source": [
"aws.glue"
],
"detail-type": [
"Glue Job State Change"
],
"detail": {
"state": [
  "FAILED"
],    

"jobName": ${value}
}
}
PATTERN
}

}
```

error i am getting -

Error: Invalid block definition

on cloudwatch.tf line 8, in resource "aws_cloudwatch_event_rule" "failed_event":
   8:   for value in range(length(var.values)):

reason why i am trying to loop this--

I am trying to loop this because of "jobname" attribute in the code. i have more than 50 job name and i want to apply this to all the job name. inittially it was working fine but list is getting grown and i am getting error that

Error: "event_pattern" cannot be longer than 2048 characters:

So i am trying to loop this.

my earlier code which was working fine until the above error(Error: "event_pattern" cannot be longer than 2048 characters:):

```
resource "aws_cloudwatch_event_rule" "failed_event" {
 name        = "failed-event"
description = "failed event"


event_pattern = <<PATTERN
{
"source": [
"aws.glue"
 ],
"detail-type": [
"Glue Job State Change"
 ],
 "detail": {
  "state": [
  "FAILED"
   ],
  "jobName": ["${join("\",\"", aws_glue_job.*.name)}"]
  }
  }
 PATTERN
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

For your original example, we could rewrite that to use [`jsonencode`](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/functions/jsonencode.html) to produce the JSON, which I think (subjectively) is easier to read and maintain:

```
resource "aws_cloudwatch_event_rule" "failed_event" {
  name        = "failed-event"
  description = "failed event"

  event_pattern = jsonencode({
    source      = ["aws.glue"]
    detail_type = ["Glue Job State Change"]
    detail = {
      state    = ["FAILED"]
      job_name = aws_glue_job.example[*].name
    }
  })
}
```

However, it sounds like your original problem was that there is a limit on how long the `event_pattern` JSON can be. Although `jsonencode` generates minified JSON and so would be marginally smaller, I doubt it will be a significant help. Instead, it seems like the path you were trying to take is to create one event rule per job. Here's one way to do that:

```
resource "aws_cloudwatch_event_rule" "failed_event" {
  # This for expression constructs a map from name to job object.
  for_each = { for j in aws_glue_job.example : j.name => j }

  name        = "failed-event-${each.key}"
  description = "${each.key} job failed"

  event_pattern = jsonencode({
    source      = ["aws.glue"]
    detail_type = ["Glue Job State Change"]
    detail = {
      state    = ["FAILED"]
      job_name = each.key
    }
  })
}
```

The above will declare one `aws_cloudwatch_event_rule.failed_event` instance for each instance of `aws_glue_job.example`, using the name of each job as the instance key. This means your event rules will have addresses like `aws_cloudwatch_event_rule.failed_event["job_name"]`, e.g. if there were a job with `name = "job_name"`.

The above will work only if the job names are constant values known at planning time, because Terraform requires that the `for_each` map keys be known during planning so that it can produce an accurate plan about how many instances will be created and what they will be called. In particular, this strategy won't work if you are using `name_prefix` instead of `name` for your `aws_glue_job.example` configuration; in that case, you'll need to use `name_prefix` as the map key, rather than `name` in order to get a key that is known during planning.

---

Note that there's a per-region limit on CloudWatch Event Rules, defaulting to 100 at the time of writing. If you have more than 50 jobs then you would already be more than halfway towards hitting that limit with this strategy of creating one rule per job, although that limit can apparently be increased by contacting AWS support while the event pattern size limit is non-negotiable.

Comment: thanks for your detailed explanation and sorry for the late reply. I will try this and let you know. much appreciated